# VS and MonoDevelop code sharing

Tags: android, .net, ios, windows-phone-7, mono

Knocking my head against the wall trying to figure out a good workflow for sharing code between a few WP7, iOS, and Android applications, all implemented in .NET/Mono.  Anyone has figured this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some experiments in code sharing that you can see here: http://granite.codeplex.com/

What I've learned so far:

1. Pure business objects are your best friend. Pushg as much logic as possible into these.
2. Testing frameworks on mobile devices are just about useless, but you can unit test the heck out of your business objects using the desktop platforms (.NET or Mono).
3. Mono has more bugs that .NET, so make sure you run your unit tests against it.
4. Make sure you use a source control that works with MonoDevelop. That means no TFS.
5. Make sure you use a Unit Test framework that Mono supports. (e.g. NUnit)
6. View-models can be shared with the right abstraction layer, but it may not be worth it.

Comment: Very close to my conclusions so far.

Answer (score 1):

I use SVN in order to code in Mono on PC/MAC/LINUX - tho i rarely do anything on Linux other than POC's.

As far as workflow for sharing libraries between all of these different systems - good luck.  All i can offer is:
- Be sure to unit test as Jonathan pointed out
- Know all of your compiler hints that are available
- Avoid P/Invoke or any O/S specific calls if possible
- Pray

Good luck :-)